# Working on a basic python calculator and can't get my menu to loop properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, calculator

Thanks to this site I was able to get this far, being the python novice I am, however I'm kind of stuck.  I'm trying to loop 'selection', so after a user does some math, rather than just ending it will give them the option to do something else until they select 0 to quit.  I tried a bunch of other try and conditional statements but just end up getting answers and such stuck in an infinite loop.

Also, I'm pretty here, but any help is appreciated, also I'm a python nub.  I'm writing this with python 2.7, if that matters.

```
def sum ( arg1, arg2):
 total = a + b
 return total;

def subtract ( arg1 , arg2):
     total = a - b
     return total;

def mult ( arg1, arg2):
     total = a * b
     return total;

def division ( arg1, arg2):
     total = (a / b) 
     return total;



options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "0"]

print ("Please choose an option for mathing")
print ("1 for addition")
print ("2 for division")
print ("3 for subtraction")
print ("4 for multiplication")
print ("5 ")
print ("0 to exit")


#this will keep prompting the user to provide an input that is listed in 'options'
while True:
    selection = input("Please select choose an option to continue")
    if selection in options:
        break

    else:
        print("Please choose a valid option")

#user input for mathing
#input will be validated as follows
a = None
while a is None:
  try:
     a = int(input("please provide a number for A"))
  except ValueError:
     print "please use a valid integer"
     pass

b = None
while b is None:
  try:
     b = int(input("please provide a number for B"))
  except ValueError:
    print "please use a valid integer"
    pass


#performing the operations

if selection == '1':
    print "The sum is", str(sum(a, b))

elif selection == '2':
    print "The quotient is", str(division(a, b))

elif selection == '3':
    print "The difference is", str(subtract(a, b))

elif selection == '4':
    print "The product is", str(mult(a, b))

elif selection == '0':
    exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a loop around the prompting and calculation. If they enter 0, break from the outer-most loop:

```
while True: 
    #this will keep prompting the user to provide an input that is listed in 'options'
    while True:
        selection = input("Please select choose an option to continue")
        if selection in options:               
            break    
        else:
            print("Please choose a valid option")                

    if selection == '0':
        break

    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I liked all the input, but this was was simple and gave the very basic functionality I needed, I'd upvote... but not enough reputation.  Always, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

heres a few things I would do to make this more efficient..

options should be a dictionary... your `in` is a lot more efficient on a dictionary than on a list. the beauty of this is the value for each key can be function methods.

ex. `options = {1: 'sum', 2: 'subtract' ..... }`

then make a class with your math operations in it

```
class Calculator(object):

    def sum(self, x, y):
        return x + y
    def subtract(self, x, y):
        return x - y

    #add more operations here

    @staticmethod
    def start():
        while True:
            #prompt for input and the operator
```

whats nice about this is in your checks for the selection you can dynamically call the class method to clean the code up a lot

```
if selection in options:
    getattr(options[selection], Calculator)(a, b)
```

if you want me to explain more I can finish the example.

for your loop, you can add a method that starts the action and continues looping and doing more operations each time

here is a basic class you can use using those methods I described

```
class Calculator(object):
    loop = None
    calculations = 1
    current_value = 0
    selection = 0
    options = {1: 'add', 2: 'subtract', 3: 'multiply', 4: 'divide'}

    def __init__(self, loop=True):
        self.loop = loop
        print 'Welcome to my basic calculator!'
        if not self.loop: # dont loop just execute once
            self.run()
        else:
            while True:
                self.run()

    @staticmethod
    def add(x, y):
        return x + y

    @staticmethod
    def subtract(x, y):
        return x - y

    @staticmethod
    def multiply(x, y):
        return x * y

    @staticmethod
    def divide(x, y):
        if y != 0: #cant divide by 0
            return x / y 

    @staticmethod
    def quit():
        exit(0)

    def run(self):
        if self.calculations == 1:
            self.current_value = self.prompt_user_input('please provide a number: ')

        self.prompt_operator('Please choose an operator to continue\n1 for addition\n2 for subtraction\n3 for multiplication \n4 for division\n0 to quit\n')
        y = self.prompt_user_input('please provide a number: ')
        self.current_value = getattr(Calculator, self.options[self.selection])(self.current_value,y)
        self.calculations += 1

        print 'New value is: ' + str(self.current_value)

    def prompt_operator(self, prompt_message):
        while True:
            self.selection = input(prompt_message)
            if self.selection in self.options:
                break
            elif self.selection == 0:
                self.quit()
            else:
                print("Please choose a valid option")

    def prompt_user_input(self, prompt_message):
        val = None
        while val is None:
            try:
                val = int(input(prompt_message))
            except ValueError:
                print "please use a valid integer"
                pass
        return val
```

finally to start your calculator off you can just call it and either pass true to continue loops or pass false to only do one calculation

```
Calculator(loop=True)
```

Comment: Wow, that's pretty thorough and kind of above my head at the moment.  I appreciate the input and it gives me  something to analyze and learn a bit from.  Thanks man.

Comment: @AdamSauer sure thing man! Any questions you have feel free to ask and I'll be more than happy to answer! Python is all about writing reusable code kinda like this :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#this will keep prompting the user to provide an input that is listed in 'options'
while True:
    selection = input("Please select choose an option to continue")
    if selection in options:
        if selection == 1:
           sum()
        if selection == 2:
           subtract()  
          .....
         if selection == 'q'
              break
```

Change the logic to what I did above, for option,take some action and do break on the quit character/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your code should not work as it is now:

```
if selection == '1':  #should return false
```

That's because using `input` you are taking a numeric quantity and then comparing it to a string.

change the `input` of `selection` to `raw_input`

Or change the conditional statements like below:

```
if selection == 1:
```

Then add a `while True` over the entire execution block to go through the execution again and again, until 0 is selected.

Comment: I followed your suggestions and it works a lot better now.  The only way it worked with input and not raw_input is if I included ' in my input, but your suggestion fixed another thing I needed to take care of!  I'd upvote, but not enough rep to do it :(.  Thanks!

Comment: @AdamSauer, nice to know it was helpful. what you can do is to accept the answer. It will help both me and the fellow users.